# Как прочитать иконку из exe файла?

Tags: c++

Я хочу экспортировать иконку из exe файла и засунуть её в другой. Нашёл этот код в интернете. Компилятор говорит что HL и PENG не определенны, в интернете не нашёл что они могут значить. Код:

```
hExe = LoadLibrary("calc.exe");
if(hExe == NULL)
{
    printf("Error loading executable\n");
    return -1 ;
}

hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(HL),RT_ICON);
if (hRes == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not locate icon.\n");
    return -1 ;
}

hResLoad = LoadResource(hExe, hRes);
if (hResLoad == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not load resource");
    return -1 ;
}

lpResLock = LockResource(hResLoad);
if (lpResLock == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not lock resource");
    return -1 ;
}

hUpdateRes = BeginUpdateResource("test.exe", FALSE);
if (hUpdateRes == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open icon file for writing.\n");
    return -1 ;
}

result = UpdateResource(hUpdateRes,RT_ICON,MAKEINTRESOURCE(PENG),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),lpResLock,SizeofResource(hExe, hRes)); 

if (result == FALSE)
{
    printf("Could not begin update resource.");
    return -1 ;
}

if (!EndUpdateResource(hUpdateRes, FALSE))
{
    printf("Could not end update resoruce");
    return -1 ;
}

if (!FreeLibrary(hExe))
{
    printf("Could not free resources");
    return -1 ;
}
```

Кто может помочь? Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: HL - это значение ID иконки в исполняемом файле, в котором вы собираетесь её менять, вам нужно найти его значение.  PENG - это значение новой иконки в вашем исполняемом файле, код которого у вас выше.

Comment: А как этот id можно найти?

Comment: Перебирать от 0 до бесконечности.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!